# HTTP Error 503 with ASP.Net DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, iis-7

I have an ASP.Net web application running on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7. A few weeks ago, something happened to the server, and I believe some Windows logins had been flushed from the system.

After getting the server back online, all our files and SQL Server databases were still intact. Some of the functionality of the web application is working properly--the users are able to log into the application (the login data is stored in an SQL Server database). Browsing to some pages, however will show a white page showing "HTTP Error 503: The service is unavailable."

The pages causing the 503 errors appear to be ones using special ASP controls, such as DataGrids.

The web project was compiled using .Net Framework 3.5. The IIS application pool on the server uses .Net Framework v2.0 with an Integrated pipeline.

Any thoughts on what I can look at to get this site back up to full functionality?

Comment: Most common reason for this error is that the application pool is running under wrong administrator credentials or unexisting one

Comment: Have you make sure you that in the advanced properties of the Application Pool in IIS, that uses the right account with the right password?

Comment: The application pool is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity, which I assume it was before the server crashed. If we lost user accounts, however, it might have corrupted that built-in identity.

Comment: Go to the Application Pools under the Server, then find the correct Application Pool for your web site, and click on it. On the Advanced Settings menu to the right, select Identity and change it and enter new user and password. Click on your Application Pool again, and select Recycle to restart it

Comment: I did notice one thing: it appears that the pages where I'm getting the 503 error are mostly in the same folder (and same namespace in the .Net code). I tried copying one of the web forms to a different folder--I could access the copy after publishing. I then created a new aspx form with just basic HTML in the folder giving me problems--I got the 503 with it, too. I compared the permissions of the two folders in the server's inetpub directory, and they appeared to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on: the folder in my web site causing the 503 error was called **Reports**, which was causing a conflict with SQL Server Reporting Services on Port 80.

We don't run the SSRS, but it was tied to Port 80.

https://seankilleen.com/2012/11/how-to-stop-sql-server-reporting-services-from-using-port-80-on-your-server-field-notes/

I started SSRS and followed the link above to change the SSRS port to 81. After making that change, I was able to access the Reports application on my web application.